# Marketing Cloud - Incorect HTTP Status Code for a Response

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, campaign

I am seeing too many instances of incorrect http status code returned by the REST API response. For example see the test results below:

**Exampale 1:** - In this example I am passing literal 'abc' as a campaign ID which expects a numeric value.

```
Request:
{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns/abc
', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers:{}}

Response:
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Mashery-Responder: 04-19
  Vary: Origin
  Connection: close
  Date: Wed, 05 Jul 2017 20:08:07 GMT
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Content-Length: 73
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}}
Response-Content:
{{
  "message": "Campaign ID is invalid",
  "errorcode": 10000,
  "documentation": ""
}}
```

As you can see the response returns StatusCode 400 - Bad Request, which in my opinion is a  correct http status code since the ID is not in the expected format/type. Now consider the example 2 below.

**Example 2:** - In this example I am passing a numeric value for the ID that does not exist on the server.

```
Request:
{Method: GET, RequestUri: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/hub/v1/campaigns/1234
', Version: 1.1, Content: , Headers:{}}

Response:
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Mashery-Responder: 04-15
  Vary: Origin
  Connection: close
  Date: Wed, 05 Jul 2017 20:29:23 GMT
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Content-Length: 74
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
}}
Response-Content:
{{
  "message": "Campaign does not exist",
  "errorcode": 10000,
  "documentation": ""
}}
```

As you can see the response also returns StatusCode 400 - Bad Request, which in my opinion is a wrong http status code. I think the right http status code should be Not Found 404.

This behavior repeats for Asset and other objects too. This makes very difficult to filter the response by http status code.

Is this a bug? Does anyone know any good reason for this to be valid?

Comment: I would argue that the first error is also incorrect; [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm) says that an "invalid value" should return a custom error code of "10005", while "10000" is nothing more than a "generic exception." I don't see why they'd have a bunch of nicely documented, custom exception codes if they're going to just return "generic exception" whenever something goes wrong. Is this a bug? I don't know, but I agree it seems weird.

Comment: I agree, the error codes returned are not correct too. For the first example the error code should be 10001 or 10005. For the second example, if http status code Not Found (404) is not returned, than at least the error code should be 10005.